# Multiple python web applications running on multiple domains (virtualhost)?

Tags: python, hosting, python-3.x, web-hosting, cherrypy

I am stuck and desperate.

Is it possible to serve multiple python web applications on multiple different domains using virtualhost on cherrypy? Hmm wait... I will answer myself: Yes, it is possible. With virtual host dispatcher it is possible, until i require this:

I need to use more instances of same application but in different versions. This means that I need to somehow split the namespace for the python `import` for these applications.

Example:
I have application `MyApp` and there are two versions of it. I have got two domains `app1.com` and `app2.com`. 
When I access `app1.com` I would like to get the application `MyApp` in version 1. When I access `app2.com`, it should be `MyApp` in version 2.

I am now using the `VirtualHostDispatcher` of `cherrypy 3.2` and the problem is that, when I use import from the methods of `MyApp` version 1 and the `MyApp` version 2 has been loaded before, python will use the already imported module (because of module cache).

Yes.. it is possible to wrap the import and clean the python module cache everytime (i use this for the top level application object instantiation), but it seems quite unclean for me... And I think that it is also inefficient...

So, what do you recommend me? 
I was thinking about using apache2 and cherrypy using Mod_WSGI, but it seems that this does not solve the `import` problem, becuase there is still one python process for all apps togetger.

Maybe, I am thinking about the whole problem completely wrong and I will need to re-think it. I am opened for every idea or tip. Only limitation is that i want to use Python 3. Anything else is still opened for discussion :-)

Thank you for every response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache/mod_wsgi can do what is required. Each mounted web application under mod_wsgi will run in a distinct sub interpreter in the same process so can be using different code bases. Better still, you use daemon mode of mod_wsgi and delegate each web application to distinct process so not risk of them interfering with each other.

Comment: Thank you. I was still thinking about that WSGI... but never gave a chance. Pitty, because it is exactly what I needed! I will just read some manuals :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what about creating myapp_selector module that does smth like that:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    import myapp1
    import myapp2
    if env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'myapp1.com':
        myapp = myapp1
    elif env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'myapp2.com':
        myapp = myapp2
    # ...
    return myapp.process_request()
```

Comment: also you can modify sys.path:
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '/path-to-myapp1/')

Comment: You missunderstood my question. It is impossible to maintain application source code with identifiers containing the version numbers. And without numbers `myapp1`, `myapp2`, your example would  not work. But thank you, Mr. Graham Dumpleton already answered :-)